# Verify that $\{Z\le x\}=\bigcap \limits _{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap \limits _{k=n}^{\infty}\{Z_k\le x+\frac{1}{m}\}$

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to verify the following

$\{Z\le x\}=\bigcap \limits _{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap \limits _{k=n}^{\infty}\{Z_k\le x+\frac{1}{m}\}$

and I can prove the inclusion  $\{Z\le x\}\subset\bigcap \limits _{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap \limits _{k=n}^{\infty}\{Z_k\le x+\frac{1}{m}\}$, but not the reverse. How might I do this? The identity is from a proof that if $Z_1(\omega),Z_2(\omega)...$ are random variables and converges pointwise to $Z(\omega)$ for every $\omega$ then $Z$ is a random variable. Mayby this fact can be used?

Also please, other approaches than mine is more than welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There must be something amiss here, as your inner intersection starts at $n$, but $n$ does seem to appear anywhere.

Comment: No, $n$ appears in the union, starts from $n=1$.

Comment: Quite right - it is my brain which is amiss this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reverse side, $w$ is in the right set iff $\forall m, \exists n_m: Z_k(w) \leq x +\frac{1}{m}$ for all $k\geq n_m$, hence $\forall m: Z(w) \leq x+\frac{1}{m}$ by the convergence (let $k\to \infty$), hence $Z(w)\leq x$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get "hence $\forall m:Z(\omega)\le x+ \frac{1}{m}$... when  $n\to \infty$ we must have less $Z_k(\omega)$ for which $Z_k(\omega)\le x+ \frac{1}{m}$, right? And then?

Comment: Let $k \to \infty$ instead. If we have $x_i \to x$ as $i\to\infty$ and $x_i \leq 1$ for all $i$, then $x\leq 1$; do you get this?

Comment: Yes, of course. So if I have undrstood you right, when $k\to \infty$ we get $\forall m lim_{k\to \infty}Z_k(\omega)\le x+\frac{1}{m}$, hence $lim_{k\to\infty}Z_k(\omega)\le x$, that is $Z(\omega)\le x$?

Comment: No, fix $m$, then let $k\to \infty$, you get $Z(w) \leq x + \frac{1}{m}$. You misorder $\forall$ signs here.

Comment: Ok, got it now! Thanks a lot!